# First error: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, future

I have a read query in a batch class which in orgs with a lot of data can bring back over 50,000 records and violate the governor limit. I am trying to hard delete records. I am using the class below to do so which is getting this error:

> First error: Too many query rows: 50001

My question is it possible to avoid this governor limit 50001?

```
global with sharing class UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch implements Database.Batchable<pse__Utilization_Detail__c>, Database.Stateful {
public String query;
private set<ID> hardDeletionList = new set<ID>();
private list<pse__Utilization_Detail__c> utilizations = new list<pse__Utilization_Detail__c>();

global UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch() {
    //constuctor 
    this.query = query;
    //@future helper method to retrieve all utilization details
    retrieveIDS(this.hardDeletionList);

    for (ID id: hardDeletionList) {
        String objectStr = 'pse__Utilization_Detail__c';

        // Convert to schema.sObjectType
        Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr);

        // Create an instance of that type
        Sobject genericObject = convertType.newSObject();

        // or if I know it is pse__Utilization_Detail__c !! why making Sobject ?
        pse__Utilization_Detail__c util = (pse__Utilization_Detail__c)convertType.newSObject();
        //switch and assign the record id
        util.Id = id;

        utilizations.add(util);
    }
    System.debug('Utilization details converted:'+utilizations.size());

}

global Iterable<pse__Utilization_Detail__c> start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
{
    //query to return all utilization details records   
    return utilizations;
} 

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, list<pse__Utilization_Detail__c> ids)
{     
    System.debug('## deleting '+ids.size()+' utilization details records');   

    //delete list of expired Case Share records
    delete ids;   
    Database.emptyRecycleBin(ids);  
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)  
{   
    //execute the batch
    UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch deleteCS = new UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(deleteCS);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}//END finish

@future(callout=true)
private static void retrieveIDS(set<ID> ids){
    ids = (new Map<Id, pse__Utilization_Detail__c>(
        [SELECT Id FROM pse__Utilization_Detail__c 
        WHERE pse__Utilization_Calculation__r.Name = 'Region Utilization - Scheduled Weekly-DO NOT USE'])).keySet();
    System.debug('Region Utilization Details - COUNTS:'+ids.size());
}}

global class UtilizationDetail_BatchScheduler implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext info) {
    UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch b = new UtilizationDetail_DeleteBatch(); 
    database.executeBatch(b, 10);
}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it won't fix your issue, never use the `global` access modifier unless you know you need it.

---

Take advantage of the `QueryLocator` pattern and iterate over your query itself:

Instead of:

```
global with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<MyObject__c>
{
    global Iterable<MyObject__c> start(...)
    {
        // query ids
    }
    // remainder of implementation
}
```

Use:

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<MyObject>
{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(...)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE ...
        ]);
    }
    // remainder of implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Larson. The upgrade worked. Now, how iterate over 50K records without hitting the governor limit? Could you help me please? Or might don't need because depend on executeBatch.size()?

Comment: That's what the batch machinery does for you. It loops over 200 at a time unless you specify a different batch size (max 2000).

Comment: Am I able to apply Dan Appleman solution to chain my batch job from finish method of another batch job? I saw this discussion https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88890/calling-batch-from-finish-of-same-batch-job

Comment: @dave Please do not ask follow up questions in the comments. If you want to ask more questions, post new ones.

Answer (score 3):

The answer that suggests using QueryLocator is a good and scalable answer.  If you're in a hurry, you could also do this by using the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT Name, ID
From Contact
Where Mailing_State = 'TX'
LIMIT 50000
```

If you're using the code on a one time basis for cleanup, this approach is probably fine.  If it's going to run regularly in production, go with the QueryLocator approach.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using 50000 instead of 49999, though.

Comment: Thx @sfdcfox. Maybe I asked this twice but am I able to apply chain batch operations in my batch class above?